# What is PriorityAttribute Used for in MSTEST / Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest

I noticed the existence of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.PriorityAttribute. From reading a little about it, it does not seem to have anything to do with the test execution order. That being the case, it begs the question: what is it used for?

I'm curious, are there any known uses of this attribute either by Visual Studio itself of any plugins/frameworks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its just extra metadata its not used for anything specific right now. The only thing that impacts the ordering of tests is using an ordered test

Answer (score 4):

In the Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer tool window, both test priorities and test categories are shown when you select the **"Traits" view**. Tests with the same priority will then be grouped together under a `Priority [x]` heading, just like test categories.

Also, mstest (the command line test runner included in visual studio) allows you to run only tests with a minimum priority. From the output of `mstest.exe /?`:

```
/minpriority:[priority]       Only tests whose priority is greater than
                              or equal to this value will be executed.
                              Example:
                              /minpriority:0 /maxpriority:2
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be used in Build Definitions (for builds on a build server) to exclude or include unit tests (a least in tfs 2010).